# how to resolve error in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

i m using ubuntu 9.04.
when i m running any command like sudo apt-get update ,i get following error
message"E: Type 'l.com/ubuntu' is not known on line 45 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
".due to this problem i m not able to download anything.please help

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is line 45 in your source.list file.  So you can fix this from the command line by `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` and commenting out line 45.  Which should be "l.com/ubuntu".

If you want to do it from a gui then goto System->Administration->Software Sources then go to the Other Software tab and find the offending repository and disable it by unchecking the check box next to it.

Once you're done with either of these do `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is corrupted. Fix the syntax error in your `sources.list` (line 45...) or replace it by a working copy.

Answer (score 0):

You've some how corrupted your /etc/apt/sources.list by inserting a E: into line 45.

It's fixable.

If your changing config files, don't forget to back them up, or put them into a revision control system.

use your favourite editor, and try and repair them problem, or revert to a backup.

I'm not sure what l.com is either, you may need to replace with a valid ubuntu mirror.

did you edit this file? any idea how it got into this state?

Answer (score 0):

line no 45 of /etc/apt/sources.list contains the statement"l.com/ubuntu jaunty partner".
But this file is read only.i m not able to change anything.please explain the process in detail

Comment: http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz 

this is good for beginners. Also consult your ubuntu getting started guides. If you new it's probably best to stick to GUI for administration.